# Difference between C programs and shell scripts receiving signals from fuser

Tags: bash, scripts, c, signal

I have written the shell script below for a lab in my college. It must look at a log file being upgraded frequently from another process and create a number of copies passed at invokation.
Here is the code (*logrotate.sh*):

```
#!/bin/bash

# Usage:
#   logrotate.sh [-n int] [-s signal] logfile
# where:
#   int is an optional integer used to make int number of copies of logfile
#   signal is the name of signal which shell command fuser must send to the process managing logfile
# this script lacks of a strong parameters checking

NCOPIES=4  
LOGSIGNAL=USR1

#use of getopts to parse the arguments  
while getopts "n:s:" OPTION ; do  
    case $OPTION in  
        n) NCOPIES="$OPTARG"  
           ;;  
        s) LOGSIGNAL="$OPTARG"  
           ;;  
        ?) printf "Usage: %s [-n copies to keep] [-s signal to send] filename\n" $(basename $0) >&2  
        exit 1  
           ;;  
    esac  
done  
#shift to read the last parameter (logfile)  
shift $(($OPTIND - 1))  
LOGFILE=$1  

#create logfile.2 logfile.3 ... logfile.NCOPIES  
for i in `seq $NCOPIES -1 1` ; do  
    test -f $LOGFILE.$i && mv $LOGFILE.$i $LOGFILE.$[ $i + 1 ]  
done  

mv $LOGFILE $LOGFILE.1  

#sending signal to process which is writing to logfile to keep on writing to $LOGFILE(original name, without any extensions)  
fuser -k -"$LOGSIGNAL" $LOGFILE.1
```

So I wrote two scripts which every second write to the file *log*:
 -the C program (*logtest.c*):

```
#include <stdio.h>  
#include <stdlib.h>   
#include <fcntl.h>  
#include <unistd.h>  

int main()  
{  
    int fd = open("log", O_WRONLY | O_APPEND);  
    if(fd < 0 ){  
        printf("Impossible to open file %s.\n", "log");  
        return -1;  
    }  
    for(;;){  
        if(write(fd, "Ciao bello mio\n", 15) != 15){  
            write(2, "Error in writing data.\n", 23);  
        }  
        sleep(1);  
    }  
    close(fd);  
    exit(0);  
}
```

-and the shell script (*logtest.sh*):

```
#! /bin/bash  

while true 
do
    echo $(date) >> log
    sleep 1
done
```

When I launch

> ./logtest.sh &
>   ./logrotate.sh log

the script *logrotate.sh* moves all the files with the correct names (*log* becomes *log.1*) and send the signal to the process which owns the file *log* for that moment (so the shell script *logtest.sh*) which then keeps on writing on the file *log*. Furthermore, it seems that there is no difference about which signal I send with fuser: it will react always the same way.

However, if I launch

> ./logtest &
>   ./logrotate.sh log

it happens that the C program *logtest* receives the signal from the command *fuser* and then terminates.

My question is: why the two logging programs have different reactions to the signal sent from fuser? I mean, why the schell script keeps on working, whilst the C program terminates?

In the man page of fuser in the RESTRICTIONS section it says

> The -k option only works on processes.

Could it be that shell scripts are not considered as real processes in the shell? This would be new for me... I have searched on Internet but no page found about *fuser* go deeply inside the signalling section.

Comment: **To close voters**: This is not OT because the question in a nutshell is: "Why doesn't `fuser` work with this `bash` script?"

Comment: Yes, it is. I am sorry kos, but I don't understand what do you mean.

Comment: Someone has voted to close this question as off-topic, and therefore this question is going to be reviewed by a number of users; since the question itself is pretty long and someone might be confused by the fact that a `C` program is mentioned, I just explained in one line why IMO this question is on-topic and is not to be closed

Comment: Yes, in fact my main doubt was about the command fuser, which seemed to me to work in different ways. Thanks to the answers received I solved this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `fuser` only works on processes currently using a file which have an opened file descriptor for them in the kernel.

While this is true for your `C` program, this is not true for your `bash` script:

```
echo $(date) >> log
```

Just opens the file, appends `stdout` to it and immediately closes it. So the file is never deemed as opened by the kernel upon `fuser`'s check.

A simple solution would be to change your `bash` script so that the file it's kept open until the `while` loop ends:

```bsh
#! /bin/bash  

while true 
do
    echo $(date) >> log
    sleep 1
done < log
```

This way a file descriptor for `log` is created upon the `while` loop's start and it's kept open until the `while` loop's end.

Answer (score 1):

Your script `logtest.sh` does only write into `log` and closes the file-descriptor immediately. So when you call `fuser` on `log.1` there is no process which has an active file-descriptor for this file.

You can simulate this by running the `while` loop inside a `list`

```
(while true; do echo $(date); sleep 1; done) >> log
```

And both `logtest.sh` and `logtest.c` will terminate no matter which `SIGNAL` you send because you doesn't handle the signal. With `bash` this can be done with `trap '<COMMAND>' USR1` (take a look at `man bash-builtins`). But I've no idea how this is done in C (never lerned C).

Comment: In C it works quite the same. The corresponding command for `trap` is `signal(SIGNAL, handler())`, where SIGNAL is the signal to handle and handle is a user defined function which accept as parameter an int corresponding to the signal number. Anyway thanks for help!